# How to copy items from one listbox in one tab page to another listbox in another tab page?

Tags: c#, tabs, listbox, listboxitem

The problem is that I can't copy items from one listbox to another listbox. In addition to that, the listboxes are in different tab pages of a tab control.

I tried some codes such as:

```
private void MoveListBoxItems(Flowerlistbox, Total1istBox)

{        
    ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection sourceItems = source.SelectedItems;

foreach (var item in sourceItems)

    {

        destination.Items.Add(item);
    }
    while (source.SelectedItems.Count > 0)

{

        source.Items.Remove(source.SelectedItems[0]);
    }
}



private void Donebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)       
{

try

{

 //moving all items from listbox1 to listbox2

Total1listBox.Items.AddRange(FlowerlistBox.Items);

  FlowerlistBox.Items.Clear();

 }

 catch (Exception ex)

 {

    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

   }

     Total1listBox.SelectedIndex = 0;

 }



foreach(var item in FlowerlistBox.SelectedItems)

{    
Total1listBox.Items.Add(item);

}




private void Donebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

              foreach(var item in FlowerlistBox.SelectedItems)

           {

             Total1listBox.Items.Add(item);

           }
```

However none of them seem to be working.

Comment: Hi, Could you provide us some code so that we will be able to help you.

Comment: did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

This will first collect the selected Items from FlowerlistBox, then add them to the Total1istBox, then remove them from FlowerlistBox and finally clear the list.

Note that your code has different spelling for FlowerlistBox and probably ought to spell TotalListBox.

```
List<object> theItems = new List<object>();
foreach (object item in FlowerlistBox.SelectedItems) theItems.Add(item);
foreach (object item in theItems) Total1istBox.Items.Add(item);
foreach (object item in theItems) FlowerlistBox.Items.Remove(item);
theItems.Clear();
```

The reason for first collecting the items is that when we finally want to remove them we can't modify the collection we would need to iterate.